# Displaying array values in the logcat

Tags: java, android, arrays, logcat

I have the following array

```
final byte[] texttoprint = new byte[]{0x1b, 0x40, 0x1b,0x74,0x0D,
       (byte) 0x91,(byte) 0x92,(byte) 0x93,(byte) 0x94,(byte) 0x95,
       (byte) 0x96,(byte) 0x97,(byte) 0x98,(byte) 0x99,
       0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A,0x0A};
```

and I want to print its values to the logcat in Eclipse, like this:

```
0x1b , 0x40
```

and so on.

I tried this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < texttoprint.length;){
  Log.i("myactivity", String.format("%20x", texttoprint[index]));
}
```

But that does an never ending loop printing 1B.

With this code:

```
Log.i("myactivity", Arrays.toString(texttoprint));
```

it prints: `[27, 64, 27...]`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: increase the `index` maybe :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop you must also increment the index for each pass in the loop.

```
for (int index = 0; index < texttoprint.length; index++){
 Log.i("myactivity", String.format("0x%20x", texttoprint[index]));
}
```

or

```
for (byte b: texttoprint){
 Log.i("myactivity", String.format("0x%20x", b));
}
```

Comment: and if i want to print all 0x1b and not only 1b?

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey Updated the code to include your comment (missed that part of the question).

Answer (score 0):

print log.

```
            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;
            for (byte b : data.data) {
                i++;
                log.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                if (i % 4 == 0) {
                    log.append(" ");
                }
            }
```